# Secure REST web service calls to restrict the access from outside of my app

Tags: angularjs, rest, security, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have developed an AngularJs website, Android & IOS mobile apps. I am using https protocol to make my web service calls more secured. I am using OAuth flow for user authentication process. Once authentication process completed, OAuth token will be sent as a response to client apps.

Anyone can get access to server resources (upload/download user files) using this OAuth token from API response. So the system is not fully secured because it is difficult to check whether the request coming from my app or outside of the app.

If someone found the OAuth access key returned from my service, they can use them to upload/download resources from outside of the app. Server resource should be more secure as it contains more sensitive user records. Please check the below image to understand the workflow. Other programs section refers to custom batch scripts, other client apps, 3rd party tools etc..

[image]

How can I restrict my REST web service to send failure response if anyone tries to access it from outside of my app?

Please provide me the way to secure my web service and server resources by resolving these security issues.

Comment: Thankfully, this will always be impossible and you must never write a web service that depends on client-side trust.

Comment: @rook is correct.  *"it is difficult to check whether the request coming from my app or outside of the app"*  is an understatement.  It is not merely difficult, it is **impossible**.

Comment: Thanks Rook and Michael for the reply. I can understand the usage of web service in client apps. But still, I want to create a secure connection between web service and client apps to make sure that no one will hack or duplicate the service calls from outside.